# Financial requirement for a tourist visa to Portugal

Tags: visas, schengen, uae

I have 15,000 dirams in my bank account. I have met all other requirements for a visa.
One lady from a consultancy company told me that I need to have the equivalent of $10,000 USD in my bank account to apply for a Schengen visa to Portugal.

Can you tell me how much I really need?

Comment: Do you mean they rejected your visa saying that? or is it just someone you asked?

Comment: Yes nean , actually I m applying through one consultancy from sarjah and when I ask for requirements she told me I shuld hav 10k dollar in my acc and it is quite surprising how can I hv 10k dollar in 3 month statement frm bank I m general sales guy, so I try to search in internet if tat is a cause then I Dnt believe for 7 days we really need 10k dollar for anywhere u planning to go as tourist, I m only talking about my class people who Lov to travel

Comment: @John if the consultancy requires you to have $10K then maybe you should not use them.  If you apply directly, do find someone to proofread your application for you.  Misspellings and nonstandard abbreviations (e.g., I m, shuld, hav, tat, Dnt, hv, acc, u) will not help your case.

Answer (score 3):

Like most countries, Portugal requires tourist visa applicants to show that they have sufficient funds for their stay.

Exactly how much is needed depends on the itinerary, but the [minimum](http://www.embassyportugal-us.org/Embassy_of_Portugal/Visa_Info_for_Schengen_States.html) given by the Portuguese embassy is:

> The minimum amount required per day is the equivalent to €40.00 plus €75.00 per entry into the country.

For a 7 day visit, this is €355. At the time I looked this up on xe.com, that worked out to [AED 1387](http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=355&From=EUR&To=AED).

Note that you may need *more* than this, depending on the specifics of your itinerary (e.g. this is not enough to stay in a 5 star hotel).

Your AED 15000 appears more than sufficient to pay for a very nice holiday.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion guys wish me good luck for nice vacation ✌️

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit minimum cash requirement for applying for a Schengen visa.  You must be able to show that you can support yourself for the duration of your intended stay.  *You can be required to prove this both at the time of your application and also when you actually present yourself at the border for admission.*

For a seven-day stay, AED 15,000 should be more than enough, but there are, of course, other considerations that might cause your application to be denied even if you have that balance in your bank account.

Comment: Yeah phoog this is my first tym to go Europe I just want to prepare clearly so no rejection can happen suggest me I m frm UAE sarjah

Comment: @John there is no way to be certain that no rejection can happen.  The best chance you have is to find a reputable lawyer, but this assumes that you can do that reliably.  I suspect that in fact it is far easier to find a disreputable lawyer than a reputable one.  It's also expensive, and you may not want to spend that kind of money.  If you don't want to hire a lawyer, your best bet is to follow the Portuguese consulate's instructions for submitting the application *very closely.*

Comment: @nean "other considerations means" other requirements???

Comment: @John Generally they might refuse you if your ties to home are weak, thinking you will not leave. And right now, for better or worse, I am sure applicants from the Middle East will be double-checked against security watch lists.

Comment: @John a security watch list is a list of people whom the country needs to watch out for, for security reasons.  For example, known terrorists and other dangerous criminals are likely to be on such a list.